# serializeObject javascript function not getting the value of the checkbox

Tags: javascript

I used a javascript function 'serializeObject' to serialize the forms, the problem that this function not getting the value of the checkbox if the checkbox is not checked.

HTML:

```
<input value="0" name="test" style="display: none;" type="checkbox">
```

Javscript:

```
jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function() {

var self = this,
    json = {},
    push_counters = {},
    patterns = {
        "validate": /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?:\[(?:\d*|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\])*$/,
        "key":      /[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|(?=\[\])/g,
        "push":     /^$/,
        "fixed":    /^\d+$/,
        "named":    /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
    };


this.build = function(base, key, value){
    base[key] = value;
    return base;
};

this.push_counter = function(key){
    if(push_counters[key] === undefined){
        push_counters[key] = 0;
    }
    return push_counters[key]++;
};

jQuery.each(jQuery(this).serializeArray(), function() {

    // skip invalid keys
    if(!patterns.validate.test(this.name)){
        return;
    }

    var k,
        keys = this.name.match(patterns.key),
        merge = this.value,
        reverse_key = this.name;

    while((k = keys.pop()) !== undefined){

        reverse_key = reverse_key.replace(new RegExp("\\[" + k + "\\]$"), '');

        if(k.match(patterns.push)){
            merge = self.build([], self.push_counter(reverse_key), merge);
        }

        else if(k.match(patterns.fixed)){
            merge = self.build([], k, merge);
        }

        else if(k.match(patterns.named)){
            merge = self.build({}, k, merge);
        }
    }

    json = jQuery.extend(true, json, merge);
});

return json;
};
```

How can allow this function to getting the value of checkbox however if the checkbox is checked or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a need to write a custom serialize function? Jquery does come with [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: @Lex Yes I need to use it like this, Can you help me to solve my problem?
NOTE: Using my function or jQuery function the both don't get the value of the checkbox if it's not checked.

Answer (score 0):

The value property for a checkbox is always going to have a truthy value. Similarly for input of `type=radio`. If the input is of one of these types you'll need to check the `checked` property.

You'll also have to account for select boxes with the `option:selected`.

Jquery tires to simplify this offering a serialise function.

I can't solve your function (if you could provide a running example through a code snippet, jsfiddle or codepen you might have better luck). But the bellow code may shed some light. Notice how the `.value` always returns the string, but `.checked` property is true/false depending on selection.

```js
let input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')

console.log(input[0].value)
// "Bike"
console.log(input[1].value)
// "Car"

console.log(input[0].checked)
// false
console.log(input[1].checked)
// true
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```